# Unique id for each control in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have a table which contains a single input control for each item in my model.  For this example let's assume my model contains 3 items.  I am able to see three rows each containing a single input and button control. I am able to click on the edit button which triggers a modal dialog box that contains the value of the input control for the row clicked.  I am able to edit this value in the modal dialog but I am not sure HOW to take that updated value and update the input control for the row clicked.  I am thinking I will need some unique identifier for each row or input control in each row in order to in turn update that value.

Main form

```
<form id="myForm">
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>      
      <tr>
        <th>Column A</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @if (Model.Items.Count > 0)
      {
        for(int 1 = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
        {
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input name="itemName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value="@Model.Items[1].Name">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button name="editItem" type="button" class="open-editItem btn btn-md btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem" title="edit item" data-id="@Model.Item[i].Name"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Modal popup

```
<div id="editItem" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Item Name</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label style="margin-right: 10px;">Item Name</label><input maxlength="100" style="width:100%;" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="closeEditItem btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnSaveItem" onclick="updateName();">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("click", ".open-editItem", function () {
    var item = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #editItem").val(item);
  });  

  function updateName() {
    var updatedItemName = $(".modal-body #editItemName").val();
        alert(updatedItemName);
        $(".input-group #itemName").val(updatedItemName);  // not working, is there a better or different way?
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You never call *updateSkillName*. The HTML markup has another, undefined function *updateName*. Did you check the console? You should have seen an error when you clicked *"Save changes"*.

Comment: Sorry, my example is pared down a bit to reduce unnecessary items.  I have updated the code.  updateName() is called.

Comment: I would suggest to avoid such mistakes and make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: good idea but I won't be able to show the model....I will work on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `window` object in order to use a `global` variable.

`Global` variables are properties of the window object.

Also, I used `closest` method in order to retain control from which it was called.

That's final code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-editItem", function () {
   window.input=$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
   var item = $(this).data('id');
   $(".modal-body #editItem").val(item);
});
function updateName() {
    var updatedItemName = $(".modal-body").find('input').val();
       alert(updatedItemName);
       $(window.input).val(updatedItemName);
}
```